# What to do with a svn-commit.tmp

Tags: svn

Every time I do a status on svn using terminal I get this file.
?      svn-commit.8.tmp

I know its a failed commit comment file but how do I get rid of it. I don't know if I should rm it or how to deal with it.

Comment: just delete it if you dont need the commit message anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just `rm` it.

The reason it's left behind when a commit fails is so that you don't lose the (potentially long) commit message that you just wrote -- you can open the file in a text editor and paste the text as the commit message of your next commit when you fix the problem that prevented your first commit.

Answer (score 107):

Removing it is just fine; it's unversioned and all of the text is stored in the SVN log anyways. If your commit fails, you can reuse it by calling:

```
svn commit -F svn-commit.tmp
```

<strike>subversion will then automatically remove your `svn-commit.tmp` file.</strike>

Comment: However, the file is not deleted automatically.

Comment: @Maxime - My commit messages are always deleted after I use the `-F` option. Maybe it's the specific version I use...

Comment: I run svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830) and the documentation (`svn help commit`) does not specify that the file is deleted : `-F [--file] ARG          : read log message from file ARG`

Comment: @Maxime - Yeah, the more I read about it across the web, it looks like I've experienced odd behavior. The SVN devs specifically made it to *not* remove the file in case you want to keep using your commit message. Since I've moved to git and no longer have SVN on this machine, I can't test it.

Comment: How in the world was this not chosen as the answer? This accurately shows what the tmp file was there for.

Comment: This will commit all files that have been modified, not just the one(s) listed in the .tmp file. Very annoying.

Comment: @klokop - The .tmp file contains the commit message that you typed in. Since the commit didn't happen due to a conflict, SVN saves your message so you can use it later...to commit all of your files that failed when the conflict happened. I think you're missing the point of the question.

Comment: Let's assume two modified files, a.txt and b.txt. Initially you try to commit a.txt (svn ci a.txt -m "commit message). This fails for some reason, and the message is saved in svn-commit.tmp. Fix whatever caused the failing, and run svn with the -F switch (svn commit ci -F svn-commit.tmp). Now b.txt will be included in the commit, although it wasn't part of the intial faild commit.

Comment: @klokop - I'm operating from the assumption that your original commit command was `svn commit`, so you rerun that with your message as `svn commit -F svn-commit.tmp`. In your scenario, you start with `svn ci a.txt ...`, so you can reuse your message _without_ committing `b.txt` with `svn ci a.txt -F svn-commit.tmp`.

Answer (score -2):

Remove it using `svn rm --force yourfilename`

better than just `rm` because `rm` doesn't make it to version tracking

Comment: This is not better, it makes no sense for this file to be added / commited.

Comment: how is this different from RustyTheBoyRobot's answer?

Comment: I don't understand what is similar between your answer and RustyTheBoyRobot's one ?
Or maybe I wasn't clear when I used the term 'commited' ?
$ svn commit -F svn-commit.tmp is useful as it uses the message inside this file to explain the change behind the commit. The file itself is not commited, so using svn rm --force svn-commit.tmp instead of rm svn-commit.tmp is just trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: commit vs rm. gotcha. It's been a while. I had to use force to get rid of it. regular rm wouldn't do it. I'm not sure what the underlying theory behind it is. I'm just going by my empirical experience. There didn't seem to be any problems by removing it.

Comment: svn rm --force yourfilename can be useful when you did a svn add yourfilename before and you don't want to commit this file, the --force is needed in this case because svn will refuse to delete a file that is changed locally as this would remove the non-saved modifications to this file.
This is the only moment this is useful, else this is needless clutter.
I downvoted this answer because this is not better as this is not the problem. This is even a confusing answer as it makes it look like the svn-commit.tmp is tracked by svn, but it is not.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Tic. I value the thinking behind it.